# Where apparmor stores information about profiles in enforce/complain mode?

Tags: firefox, apparmor

Where does AppArmor store information about which profiles should be loaded on system start in *enforce* or *complain* mode? What happens when I do `aa-enforce /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox`?

My problem is, that I somehow broke some Firefox functionality, even though I have restored `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox` (and reinstalled Firefox from repositories) and did `aa-enforce`. (From logs I see that AppArmor is blocking something.) I would like to check HDD backup to see if, that profile had been enforced in the first place (before I broke everything), but I don't know where to look.

I'm using Linux Mint 19, 4.15.0-45-generic.

Answer (score 0):

The aa-enforce and aa-complain commands edit the profile in place. The aa-disable command creates a symlink in /etc/apparmor.d/disable pointing to the profile.

<strike>As I understand, this command does not persist across reboots. It simply changes the status of the profile for the current boot.</strike>

Comment: I have tested it again. Somehow when I did `aa-enforce /etc/apparmor.d/firefox`, it persisted trough reboot. Same with disabling (`aa-disable`). I have tested it also with my custom made profile just to be sure.